# How to use ESC key to cycle between modes?

Tags: vim, vi

I have been tweaking my vimrc lately. I was wondering if I can use the ESC key to cycle between Insert-Normal-Command modes and use SHIFT+ESC to cycle backwards.

Is it possible and has somebody done this before?

Answer (score 3):

Generally mapping things to <kbd>esc</kbd> causes bad things to happen, so I wouldn't suggest it. Furthermore, a lot of terminals don't get the <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>esc</kbd> key. I find that, for the most part, learning the default way that vim maps things pays off. Deviations should be very special cases or personal option setting.

Comment: Yes, SHIFT+ESC causes some problems, So I have mapped the F1 to ESC (Which i dont use normally to open help)

Comment: Generally mapping things to ESC causes bad things to happen, so I wouldn't suggest it.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed ESC mapping, Instead F1 now cycles the n-c-i modes. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Also, just for the knowledge, could you please tell what kind of things can happen if ESC key was mapped accidentally? When I tried the ESC mapping it worked fine.

Comment: Certain plugins and potentially built-in plugins or functions may use the ESC key to perform standard features of vim. Even though the ESC key may work fine at first, you would probably notice a couple weeks later that something odd has stopped working without explanation.

Comment: There's also a slight delay when hitting `<Esc>` that may be undesirable in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

Now ESC cycles Normal-Command-Insert modes. Will update the answer once I get F1 to cycle backwards.

```
"   F1 is ESC
nnoremap <F1> <ESC>
inoremap <F1> <ESC>
vnoremap <F1> <ESC>

"   ESC Cycles n-c-i modes
nmap <ESC> :
cnoremap <ESC> <ESC>i
```

EDIT: As per advise, I did not map the ESC directly, I have now mapped the F1 key to cycle n-c-i modes.

```
"   F1 Cycles n-c-i mode
nmap <F1> <ESC> :
inoremap <F1> <ESC>
vnoremap <F1> <ESC>
cnoremap <F1> <ESC> <ESC>i
```